# Fixed overlapping jquery panel

Tags: jquery, html, css

My plan with this site is to add a header to the page which remains fixed as you scroll through the page. The catch though is that this header needs to also slide down and reveal a panel while overlaying the main content and not push it down. I've tried `position:fixed` on the header and/or panel div but it somehow hides the scroll bars. I've also tried using `z-index` but that doesn't have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code.

[My HTML](http://tny.cz/22de6520)

[And my CSS](http://tny.cz/4f9d59aa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you had an extra div tag under your `div#main_header` that didn't have a closing one.

I tested it out in my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Morlock0821/mfF4X/1/

I also removed `position:absolute` and `top:0` from your `#header` css and just added `position:fixed`.

It seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

http://limpid.nl/lab/css/fixed/header

Hope it helped :)